# How to make bootstrap column height to remaining screen height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I have a web page with a navbar, a sidebar, and a table inside the main content. My simplified code is as follows:

```html
<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark py-2 sticky-top">
    <!-- navbar content -->
  </nav>

  <!-- Actual Content -->
  <div class="container-fluid flex-grow-1">
    <div class="row h-100">

      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 d-none d-md-flex h-100 flex-column sidebar">
        <!-- sidebar content -->
      </div>

      <!-- Content -->
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 flex-sm-column">
        <div class="main-content w-100 d-flex flex-grow-1">
          <!-- table with variable height -->
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
<body>
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh !important;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* FOR SIDEBAR */
.sidebar {
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid var(--light-grey);
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

/* TABLE */
.main-content {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table {
  margin: 0;
}
```

What I intend to happen is for the body to always have the height of the screen. When the table is small, this is achieved but when the table overflows, the body's height increases. How do I make it so that `content` takes only the remaining height of the screen, and any overflow (from the table) is taken on `main-content` instead of the body?

I tried setting the height of everything to 100%, as well as played around with flex-grow properties, but nothing seemed to work. Do tell if I still need to include more specific details but that's everything that actually makes use of dimension properties.

Comment: add `max-height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;` to `body`. And remove `html` from your first line of css. You can set `height: 100%;` to `html`. Nothing else is needed here.

Comment: @Shuvo this doesn't solve my problem. The table is still overflowed on the body but now it's just hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the container column relative then you can position your main-content absolutely to fill the column and have overflow auto on the content:

```css
@import url("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css");

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* FOR SIDEBAR */

.sidebar {
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.main-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark py-2 sticky-top">
  navbar content
</nav>

<!-- Actual Content -->
<div class="container-fluid flex-grow-1">
  <div class="row h-100">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 d-none d-md-flex h-100 flex-column sidebar">
      sidebar content s
    </div>

    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 relative">
      <div class="main-content">
        table with variable height <br>
        s<br>s<br>s<br>s<br>s<br>s<br> s
        <br>s<br>s<br>s<br>s<br>s<br> s
        <br>s<br>s<br>s<br>s<br>s<br> s
        <br>s<br>s<br>s<br>s<br>s<br>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know before that setting all sides of an absolute element to 0 would fill up the whole container.